# nginx php files being downloaded by the browser, not processed

Tags: nginx

I've been hitting my head against the wall trying to figure this out.

I'm trying to add a /knowledge subdirectory which points to a wordpress blog. However nginx isn't processing the files, it's serving them to the browser to download.

Please help!

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen   [::]:80;
    server_name domain.com;

    return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
 }

server {
    listen 443  ssl;
    server_name domain.com;

    ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/domain_com-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/domain_com.key;

    root /opt/domain.com/public/;

     location / {
        try_files $uri @backend;
      }


    location @backend {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3030;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    #knowledge wordpress config

    location ^~ /knowledge {
        alias /opt/domainWordpress/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ knowledge/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
      }

      location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you installed and configured PHP-FPM or similar to handle the PHP processing? You don't have any section in your Nginx config to catch PHP requests and forward them to a PHP backend.

Comment: hm. Yeah i've installed php-fpm. Do you know of a tutorial to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

nginx process requests using a single `location` block. You should read on [how nginx processes requests](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

Your problem comes from the fact the location handling your URI (`/knowledge[...]`) differs from the on handling ones targeted at PHP (`/[...].php` I suppose).

Since you used the special `^~` [`location`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) operator, regex `location` blocks are not being checked when selecting the properest one to server your requests, if this block matches. As a consequence of your request being served by this block (longest prefix), it simply serves the files from disk, with the [default MIME type](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#default_type) having been configured.

You could try nesting `location ~ \.php$` block inside `location ^~ /knowledge` block.